# Displaying on a local machine when running on a server

Tags: linux, matplotlib, ipython, remote-server, xserver

I imagine what I am wanting to do is quite a regular issue but having had a search I can't find a solution. Basically I am running Ipython on a remote server and I want to be able to use matplotlib and then it display on my local machine.

The issue is with me not being able to connect to the X server it seems. Here is what I am getting when I try to run matplotlib

```
In [1]: %matplotlib
 : cannot connect to X server
```

Any ideas anyone? Like I say I would imagine this must be a pretty common issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing `-X` option (that's a capital X) to your ssh command. This should enable X11 forwarding.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not using an ssh command to connect however, I am logging in using PuTTY.

Comment: You might want to look at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/119792/how-to-use-x11-forwarding-with-putty) then.